# how do I insert a 'cut in a scale'?

Tags: r, scale, adapt

does anyone know a code in R for this sign (or something like it, see attached Image) in the scale? I would like to use it for a kaplan-meier curve, where only few deaths occurred and therefore I would like to adapt the scale to it.
thanks a lot in advance!

[image]

Comment: Have a look at: https://cran.r-project.org/web//packages/ggbreak/vignettes/ggbreak.html assuming you want to go down the `ggplot` route. It would be easier to help if you include a [MRE]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.